# Angular 2 nested property isn't detected by object - Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a component that fetches data from the server and the server returns a string JSON just like:

```
"{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": "5",
  "addresses": [
    {"street": "123 Street", "city": "Main City"} 
  ]
}"
```

So when I receive this in my component I do:

```
let result = JSON.parse(response); //response is the JSON string from server
```

Then since I need to display all the addresses I'm using a ngFor to display it. The problem is the address doesn't display. And when I display even just the length of the address it displays zero. So I tried to print on the console the whole object it also displays no content for addresses but if I print just the addresses by doing:

```
console.log(result['addresses']) or console.log(result.addresses);
```

it displays the content which is weird. So hope someone can help me.

Comment: May need to show your *ngFor snippet too, as that's likely where the problem is.  The JSON.parse(response) looks fine.  result.address should be undefined, as "address" is not "addresses".

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to use ngFor with result instead of result.address

Comment: Do post your html that you are using to display this response in UI

Comment: I think we'll have to assume that the html is correct, and also regardless of the html the `console.log(result.addresses)` is working but when I print using `console.log(result)` only the addresses is empty.

Comment: Or we'll have to assume that there are other errors in your code (html or javascript) since nothing here is even remotely complex enough to produce the behavior you are describing. Without showing the code you'll need the help of a psychic, not stack overflow. But here is a wild guess to entertain you: Perhaps the adress has not yet resolved when/where you try to output it?

Comment: I think my English is not good cause nobody understands the problem. That's okay thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Please don't mind. Its not about english but its about how you present your problem. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the issue is with how you are trying to access the address. Your addresses is an  array objects. So you use `*ngFor` to display that. Your Component template should look like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      Name:{{data.name}}<br>
      <label *ngFor="let a of data.addresses">
        Street:{{a.street}}
        City:{{a.city}}
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

and you are good to Go. Here is a **[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ybJSKhrzOwH78CTxhzdi?p=preview)** of the Same.

Here is the result of the `console.log(result.addresses)` and `console.log(result)` Have updated the same in Plunker also can verify. Below is the snap of the same
[image]

Hope it Helps :)

Comment: As you can see my json isn't an array, only the addresses is an array. and the console is just a typo error i've edited it already.

Comment: Ok fine. But i think you still should post your html how you are trying to display this data onto UI. Because as you can see in the plunker demo it working fine. And can you please tell me why this downvote?

Comment: @Jed have updated the answer based on your comments. And also we cant just assume that the HTML is correct. Because The demo i have provided seems to work absolutely fine. So that clearly means there is some issue with your code.

Comment: That's my template also. But that's not even the first problem. How would you explain that when I print `console.log(result.addresses)` there are addresses then when I print the whole thing `console.log(result)` the addresses is empty?

Comment: @Jed Yes have added a console output snap to justify what should happen. And updated the plunker also for the same. Please veriy that there are no issues with your code. Or create a demo replicating your problem. That only can help us solve it.

Comment: No I can't replicate the code. I guess there's a big problem in my code. I just thought maybe somebody also experienced this before. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thats why unless we can find the problem. I dont think we can help you or point you to the right solution. :)

Answer (score -2):

You have to escape the quotation marks when you put the string representation of the object in a string using quotation mark, use apostrophes as string delimiter.

```
'{
 "name": "John Doe",
 "age": "5",
 "addresses": [
    {"street": "123 Street", "city": "Main City"} 
 ]
}'
```

This should work.

Comment: He was just using the double quotes to indicate that it was a string.

Comment: There are some instances where the data is wrapped inside the double quotes if that's the scenario then JSON.parse() would throw errors. That's why I suggested him to use apostrophes as a string delimiter. Nvm